# Plot weighted frequency matrix

Tags: r, matrix, probability, frequency, weighted

This question is related to two different questions I have asked previously:

1) [Reproduce frequency matrix plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913006/reproduce-frequency-matrix-plot)

2) [Add 95% confidence limits to cumulative plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6155588/add-95-confidence-limits-to-cumulative-plot)

I wish to reproduce this plot in R:[image: boringmatrix]

I have got this far, using the code beneath the graphic:[image: multiplot]

```
#Set the number of bets and number of trials and % lines
numbet <- 36 
numtri <- 1000 
#Fill a matrix where the rows are the cumulative bets and the columns are the trials
xcum <- matrix(NA, nrow=numbet, ncol=numtri)
for (i in 1:numtri) {
x <- sample(c(0,1), numbet, prob=c(5/6,1/6), replace = TRUE)
xcum[,i] <- cumsum(x)/(1:numbet)
}
#Plot the trials as transparent lines so you can see the build up
matplot(xcum, type="l", xlab="Number of Trials", ylab="Relative Frequency", main="", col=rgb(0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.02), las=1)
```

My question is: **How can I reproduce the top plot in one pass, without plotting multiple samples?**

Thanks.

Comment: Despite the fact that you had a more path-deterministic graphic in mind, I thought your transparency-weighted graph was better at illustrating the statistical nature of this question. I suppose it could have been outlined by: `lines(6:36, 6/(6:36), lty=3)` to show that extremal possibilities.)

Comment: @DWin Funnily enough I am now banging my head trying to create some kind of density heatmap (or hexbin) so it's more like the transparent-weighted version. If you've got a good idea how to create it, I can ask a new question? I was thinking of something like [this](http://www.actualanalytics.com/density-plot-heatmap-using-r-a58).

Comment: That link's not working for me at the moment, but I have learned a lot from your questions so I encourage you to ask more.

Comment: @DWin This is making my brain hurt. Here is the link to my new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7305803/plot-probability-heatmap-hexbin-with-different-sized-bins).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can produce this plot...

[image]

... by using this code:

```
boring <- function(x, occ) occ/x

boring_seq <- function(occ, length.out){
  x <- seq(occ, length.out=length.out)
  data.frame(x = x, y = boring(x, occ))
}

numbet <- 31
odds <- 6
plot(1, 0, type="n",  
    xlim=c(1, numbet + odds), ylim=c(0, 1),
    yaxp=c(0,1,2),
    main="Frequency matrix", 
    xlab="Successive occasions",
    ylab="Relative frequency"
    )

axis(2, at=c(0, 0.5, 1))    

for(i in 1:odds){
  xy <- boring_seq(i, numbet+1)
  lines(xy$x, xy$y, type="o", cex=0.5)
}

for(i in 1:numbet){
  xy <- boring_seq(i, odds+1)
  lines(xy$x, 1-xy$y, type="o", cex=0.5)
}
```

Comment: That really helps. I have been banging my head against a brick wall for days now, and with a deadline looming. I can now get on with some things. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Koshke's method, by limiting the combinations of values to those with s<6 and at Andrie's request added the condition on the difference of Ps$n and ps$s to get a "pointed" configuration.

```
 ps <- ldply(0:35, function(i)data.frame(s=0:i, n=i))
 plot.new()
 plot.window(c(0,36), c(0,1))
 apply(ps[ps$s<6 & ps$n - ps$s < 30, ], 1, function(x){
   s<-x[1]; n<-x[2];
   lines(c(n, n+1, n, n+1), c(s/n, s/(n+1), s/n, (s+1)/(n+1)), type="o")})
 axis(1)
 axis(2)
 lines(6:36, 6/(6:36), type="o")
 # need to fill in the unconnected points on the upper frontier
```

[image: Resulting plot (version 2)]

Comment: Except that the number of trials aren't limited to 31, as in the original question.  (Compare the shape of the graphs at the right hand edge.)

Comment: Oh. Alright. Will add the logical condition to accomplish that.

Comment: Andrie : Thanks for the vote. Returned the favor. I did try using your `boring` function when I first tackled thi,s but confess that I did not understand it as well as the plyr approach that koshke used. I didn't really understand how the 4-tuples worked with `lines` but I could see the structure of @koshke's "ps" object better.

Comment: @Dwin Agreed.  My first attempt at the boring function (in previous question) was rather muddled and didn't extend easily.  I had to re-engineer it from scratch to make this new plot. In its new form I think it is easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 0):

Weighted Frequency Matrix is also called Position Weight Matrix (in bioinformatics).
It can be represented in a form of a [sequence logo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_logo).
This is at least how I plot weighted frequency matrix.

```
library(cosmo)
data(motifPWM); attributes(motifPWM) # Loads a sample position weight matrix (PWM) containing 8 positions.
plot(motifPWM) # Plots the PWM as sequence logo.
```